# Nuxt - HTML Injection by Webpack plugin

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

Currently I'm migrating a Vue.js App to an Nuxt.js App. In our previous setup we used [favicons-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/favicons-webpack-plugin) to generate favicons during compile-time. These were then injected into the HTML with [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin).

As we want to achieve the same functionality after the migration we need a way to generate these favicons. We came across [nuxt-rfg-icon](https://github.com/pimlie/nuxt-rfg-icon) Nuxt-plugin but it does not provided the same feature-set (less generated favicons & the favicons are converted by an online service).

Generally speaking one could use webpack-plugins in Nuxt. So i tried integrating the webpack-plugin, but these favicons are only injected in one of two generated HTML-files. A `index.spa.html` (favicons present) and a `index.ssr.html` (favicons *not* present). When the Page is rendered by Nuxt on the serverside it seems to use the `index.ssr.html` (seems expected).

So I made a little dive into the @nuxt/webpack package to get some info about how Nuxt configures webpack. There I found this code:

```js
// Generate output HTML for SSR
if (buildOptions.ssr) {
  plugins.push(
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin__default['default']({
      filename: '../server/index.ssr.html',
      template: appTemplatePath,
      minify: buildOptions.html.minify,
      inject: false // Resources will be injected using bundleRenderer
    })
  );
}
```

There it says that webpack should disable the automatic injection because the bundleRenderer is doing this. Unfortunately I could not find any resources online on how to inject the HTML of a webpack-plugin into the bundleRenderer. Maybe this is not possible or even intended?

So here is my actual question: How can i get Nuxt to work with the `favicons-webpack-plugin`?

Answer (score 0):

I think if the injection configuration item (v6.0.1) of https://github.com/jantimon/favicons-webpack-plugin does not meet your needs to modify **.nuxt/server/index.ssr.html**, you can consider :

- rewriting the plugin using nuxt module
- implementing it yourself with nuxt modue.

These are the corresponding documentations:

https://nuxtjs.org/api/internals-builder

https://nuxtjs.org/api/internals-renderer

https://nuxtjs.org/api/internals-generator

I wrote an article related can refer to https://github.com/yanyue404/blog/issues/263.